# does solr 3.6 use apache lucene for sorting?

Tags: solr, lucene

As i know solr is built upon lucene , but does solr has its own code for sorting or other functionality like searching etc.

or it use apache lucene for all core functionality like searching, sorting ?

Mainly i want to know in solr does apache solr has its own way for sorting or sorting is as same as lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr uses Lucene for everything that Lucene supports, and builds its own stuff on top of that (such as the HTTP API, Cloud / replication support, etc.).

Most core, low-level functionality, such as searching and sorting, uses  Lucene (after all, that's what Lucene does, and does well).